# How to rewrite this using Object Oriented Programming? remove statics, create object, prefix methods with object name...? what else?

Tags: object, oop, static, final

Can someone help me understand how to make the following using object-oriented programming?
It is a short program that compares how quickly two different sort algorithms run on arrays of various sizes. When trying to rewrite it using object orientation, I start by making an object called "OO" at the top of Main, then prefixing all the method calls with "OO.", then remvoing all the static modifiers, but it still throws errors. I'm sure there is an easy fix, I'm just very new to this. Thanks.  (below is the version that runs, with no attempt yet at OOP)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

public class SortingExercise {

```
//Create constants to give array size

final static int CONST100 = 100000; // The length of arrays that will be sorted.
final static int CONST10 = 10000; // The length of arrays that will be sorted.
final static int CONST1 = 1000; // The length of arrays that will be sorted.

final static int CONSTMIL = 1000000; //Constant for use in making/sorting a million-element array 

/*
 * Creates an array populated with random integers varying widely in size
 * @param count : the length of the array that is created.
 */

private static int[] randomInts(int count) {
    int[] numbers = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        numbers[i] = (int)(Integer.MAX_VALUE * Math.random());
    return numbers; 
}

/*
 * Sorts an array of integers using the selection sort algorithm.
 */
private static void selectionSort(int[] numbers) {
    for (int end = numbers.length-1; end > 0; end-- ) {
        int maxloc = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= end; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] > numbers[maxloc])
                maxloc = i;
        }
        int temp = numbers[end];
        numbers[end] = numbers[maxloc];
        numbers[maxloc] = temp;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double startTime;
    double runTime; 

    int[] Array1;
    int[] Array2;

    //FIRST RUN - 1,000 ELEMENTS
    //Create Arrays

    Array1 = randomInts(CONST1);
    Array2 = Arrays.copyOf(Array1, CONST1);

    //Sort and print comparative run times of selectionSort and the Array.sort method on identical 1,000-element arrays
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    selectionSort(Array1); 
    runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println(runTime + " milliseconds for Array1 with 1,000 elements using selectionSort");

    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    Arrays.sort(Array2); 
    runTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime; 
    System.out.println(runTime/1000000 + " milliseconds for Array2 with 1,000 elements using built-in Array.sort method");
    System.out.println();

    //SECOND RUN - 10,000 ELEMENTS
    //Create Arrays

    Array1 = randomInts(CONST10);
    Array2 = Arrays.copyOf(Array1, CONST10);

    //Sort and print comparative run times of selectionSort and the Array.sort method on identical 10,000-element arrays
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    selectionSort(Array1); 
    runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println(runTime + " milliseconds for Array1 with 10,000 elements using selectionSort");

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Arrays.sort(Array2); 
    runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime; 
    System.out.println(runTime + " milliseconds for Array2 with 10,000 elements using built-in Array.sort method");
    System.out.println(); 

    //THIRD RUN - 100,000 ELEMENTS
    //Create Arrays

    Array1 = randomInts(CONST100);
    Array2 = Arrays.copyOf(Array1, CONST100);

    //Sort and print comparative run times of selectionSort and the Array.sort method on identical 100,000-element arrays
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    selectionSort(Array1); 
    runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println(runTime + " milliseconds for Array1 with 100,000 elements using selectionSort");

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Arrays.sort(Array2); 
    runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println(runTime + " milliseconds for Array2 with 100,000 elements using built-in Array.sort method");
    System.out.println();



    //OPTIONAL FINAL RUN ONLY USING .sort() -> 1 MILLION ELEMENTS

    //Create Array

    Array1 = randomInts(CONSTMIL);

    //Sort and print runtime for a million-element array
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Arrays.sort(Array1); 
    runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println(runTime + " milliseconds for Array1 with 1 million elements using built-in Array.sort method");


    //END PROGRAM   
}
```

}

Comment: Since you have working code, you might have a [good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) rather than SO.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! @[type here] the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* .  Note that specific re-write requests are off-topic, though answers may choose to suggest replacement code.

Comment: Before I take it to code review, let me clarify: I'm not looking for a rewrite - I just need a quick explanation of what to change in order to convert this to OOP. I can then implement any guidance on my own.